# Excel - Highlight rows based on set conditions

Tags: excel, vba, formula

Is it possible to highlight rows where the employee Number is the same, but has more than one Job Name and at least one of those Job Names has to contain the word "Manager"? So in the case below, The employee number 12 rows would be highlighted because it has more than one Job Name and one of those Job names contains the word "Manager". Would something like this be done in VBA, Conditional Formatting, Formulas, or any other methods?

[image]

Comment: Yes this is possible. Have you attempted to do this yourself?

Comment: @MichaelMurphy Would it be done with formulas, VBA, conditional formatting, or any other method??

Comment: I would start with conditional formatting but this can be done with VBA or using formulas (in a helper column) also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Conditional Formatting. Assuming that your data is in cells A1:D11, highlight the whole column A, go to Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,$A1,$D$2:$D$11,"*manager*")
```

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: @CameronCole Note: if you want the entire row highlighted, instead of just column A values, change `A1` to `$A1`.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the formula to do this for Employee Numbers with more than one Job name that includes the manager? It's still picking up Employee numbers with One Job name.

Comment: If you want to highlight employees that are having at least one managerial position, then you can simply add ">1" at the end of the formula: =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,$A1,$D$2:$D$11,"*manager*")>1
So, for example, employee no 12 won't be currently highlighted because it only holds one managerial position. Does it help?

Comment: Sorry I might not be explaining myself properly. I mean any employee with more than 1 Job Name (not necessarily more than one managerial title). So employee no 12 will still be highlighted because it has both a manager and a random Job Name.

Comment: Got it - sorry for the confusion. Try multiplying your original formula by another condition (we are checking if EE number appeared more than once - this should let us know how many positions a given employee holds): `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,$A1,$D$2:$D$11,"*manager*")*(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$11,$A1)>1)`
Let me know if it works for your dataset.